# Where can I find isogloss maps for Mandarin?

Tags: phonology

It seems that questions about resources are generally accepted on the site. If not, please let me know.

I was wondering if anyone knew where to find maps with isoglosses for dialects of Mandarin. I am especially interested in phonemic features, such as

- erhua
- mergers, such as eng/en, in/ing, x/sh etc.
- regional differences in tones

but anything would be interesting.

Answer (score 10):

The shapes of Isogloss maps are generally identical to those of dialect maps. So I think this could give you some clues.
[image]

Below is a sample for isogloss maps(from http://www.yupoo.com/photos/9919/7485900/)
[image]

More of them:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Suggestion: For more information about isogloss maps, visit http://image.baidu.com/ and type in "同言线". Further reading: http://book.kongfz.com/15325/226467644/ This is a book about chinese linguistic geography. For more books in this subject, search "汉语方言地理学".

Answer (score 3):

You can try [乡音苑(phonemica)](http://phonemica.net), it has dialects map in both English and Chinese, maybe you can find isogloss maps.

[image]